# How to hide "optional string" from \cite[optional string]{key}

Tags: citing

How can I hide the "optional string" from `\cite[optional string]{key}` without removing it? Is there a global switch which disables printing the "optional string"?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite[page 1]{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{lamport94}
    Leslie Lamport,
    \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
    Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
    2nd edition,
    1994.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

But I'd like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `\cite` is followed by `[`, it does `\@tempswatrue`, otherwise it does `\@tempswafalse`. When `\if@tempswa` returns true, it means that the optional argument should be typeset.

So changing `\@tempswatrue` into `\@tempswafalse` will do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\cite}{\@tempswatrue}{\@tempswafalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite[page 1]{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{lamport94}
    Leslie Lamport,
    \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
    Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
    2nd edition,
    1994.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option. The idea here is to redefine `\@cite` to reject typesetting the note. Two commands are defined: `\Rejectcitenote`, to discard the optional argument, and `\Alllowcitenote` to, well, allow typesetting the optional argument. These commands can be used at will:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Rejectcitenote{\def\@cite##1##2{[{##1}]}}
\newcommand\Allowcitenote{\def\@cite##1##2{[{##1\if@tempswa , ##2\fi}]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Rejectcitenote
\cite[page 1]{lamport94}
\Allowcitenote
\cite[page 1]{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{lamport94}
    Leslie Lamport,
    \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
    Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
    2nd edition,
    1994.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]