# Hide additional citation argument "p. 11" from `\cite[p.~11]{kim2011}` output

Tags: bibtex, citing

I use the additional field in cite (e.g., `\cite[§3.3]{Knu86}`) to link to the specific part of the book/paper where I am referring to. However, I am not allowed to use this format for my thesis.

Is it possible to hide the additional text (e.g., §3.3) from the output while keeping it in the actual citation? For example, by redefining `\cite` somehow?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

This works, yeah! \cite[p. 83]{Knu86}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Double check with your advisor that you are *really* not allowed to add page numbers or other pinpoint references to citations. That sort of additional info is very valuable and should not be suppressed!

Comment: BTW: Not that it would matter if you have to suppress the page reference, but I would write `\cite[p.~83]{Knu86}` with a `~` after the `p.` to avoid an undesirable line break and a sentence-end space.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely check it out with my supervisor as I think it's useful for the readers too.

Comment: Didn't see that before, but this post is a duplicate, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251391/107626) for other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! The following two lines do the trick.

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\oldcite{#2}}
```

The first line copies the definition of the `\cite`-macro to the macro `\oldcite`. Renewing the command with the same number of parameters (two) and one optional value while only parsing the second parameter, the citation key, to the original `cite`-macro while ignoring the first one basically replaces every `\cite[...]{bib-key}` by `\cite{bib-key}`.

The complete file then looks like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\oldcite{#2}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

This works, yeah! \cite[p. 83]{Knu86}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I also removed the comma from the bib-entry-line with the title as it stopped BiBTeX from properly parsing the file in my system.

Comment: Meanwhile I switched to `biber` from `biblatex`. Trying to use this trick now leads to a never ending compilation. Not sure if this is related to biber, though. Is there any limitation of this solution?

Comment: Looks like Biber is just extremely slow compared to BibTeX/BibLaTeX, see tex.stackexchange.com/a/230800/107626. Although it generally compiles well without your `\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\oldcite{#2}}` command (I also removed the auxiliary files before recompiling). Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I found that the template made some changes so that the additional "note" field in `\cite` was used as a category.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using additional citation packages and thus use the definitions from the kernel, you can redefine the internal macro that places the citation and the postnote to simply drop the postnote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1}]}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year   = {1986},
  title  = {The \TeX book},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This works, yeah! \cite[p.~83]{Knu86}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The original definition of that macro from `latex.ltx` is

```
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
```

where `#1` is the citation label and `#2` the postnote (and `\if@tempswa` a test if the postnote is present).